# How can i use Drools business rule engine with python application?

Tags: python, drools, rule-engine, business-rules

I Need a scalable business rule engine, i think Drools is good one. How can i use this Drools business rule engine with python application?

If Drools is not suitable with python, please suggest a good one for python?

Thanks in advance,
Jerin John

Comment: Software Recommendations is probably a better suited stackexchange. Did you have a look at https://pypi.org/project/Intellect/

Comment: Thanks Hristo Vrigazov

Comment: What about using it with jython?

Comment: @jerinjo what did you use in the end?

Answer (score 9):

Those rule engines in python are:

- [pyDatalog](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/home)
- [Pyke](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/logic_programming/index.html)
- [PyCLIPS](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/)
- [durable_rules](https://github.com/jruizgit/rules)
- [Intellect](https://github.com/nemonik/Intellect)
- [business-rules](https://github.com/nemonik/Intellect)
- [PyKnow](https://github.com/buguroo/pyknow)

Relative question link in stackoverflow:

- [Python Rule Based Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421492/python-rule-based-engine)
- [Open Source based Rules Engines in Java or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010260/open-source-based-rules-engines-in-java-or-python)
- [Implementing a "rules engine" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467738/implementing-a-rules-engine-in-python)
- [Rules Engine in C or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925360/rules-engine-in-c-or-python)