# Variable scope + eval in Clojure

Tags: binding, clojure, eval, let

In Clojure,

```
(def x 3)
(eval '(prn x))
```

prints 3, whereas

```
(let [y 3]
   (eval '(prn y)))
```

and

```
(binding [z 3] (eval '(prn z)))
```

generate an 'Unable to resolve var' exception.

According to http://clojure.org/evaluation, `eval`, `load-string`, etc generate temporary namespaces to evaluate their contents.  Therefore, I'd expect neither of the above code samples to work, since `(def x 3)` is done in my current namespace, not the one created by `eval`.

1. Why does the first code sample work and not the last two?
2. How can I `eval` a form with bound variables without using `def`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1.:

The reason this doesn't work is (more or less) given on the page you linked:

```
It is an error if there is no global var named by the symbol […]
```

And:

> […]
>
> 4. A lookup is done in the current namespace to see if there is a mapping
>      from the symbol to a var. If so, the
>      value is the value of the binding of
>      the var referred-to by the symbol.
> 5. It is an error.

`eval` evaluates forms in an empty ([null](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/glo_n.html#null_lexical_environment) in CL-lingo) lexical environment. This means, that you cannot access lexical variable bindings from the caller's scope. Also, `binding` creates new bindings for existing vars, which is why you cannot use it "by itself", without having `declare`d or `def`ed the variables you try to bind. Besides, lexical variables (at least in CL, but I would be surprised if this wasn't the case for Clojure) already ceased to exist at runtime – They are translated to addresses or values.

See also my [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575262/executing-a-dynamically-bound-function-in-clojure/2575425#2575425) about this topic.

2.:

So, you have to use dynamic variables. You can avoid the explicit `def`, but you still at least need to `declare` them (which `def`s var names without bindings):

```
user=> (declare ^:dynamic x)
#'user/x
user=> (binding [x 10] (eval '(prn x)))
10
nil
```

By the way: I suppose you know why you need eval, and that its use is [considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil) when other solutions would be appropriate.

Comment: Note that this won't work in Clojure 1.3. You'll have to use `(declare ^:dynamic x)`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand my problem now -- I was assuming that "null lexical scope" also meant in a "null namespace", but quick testing reveals that `eval` works within the current namespace, which is why it has access to namespace vars but not lexical variables.

Very nice answer, and your links were helpful as well!

Comment: I guess you should quote the inner (prn x).

Comment: I ran into this issue while trying to write a macro that would automate  something like `(let [x 41, y (inc x)] {:x x, :y y})` (obviously only interesting with large let blocks and lots of chewy math). I tried `(defmacro hashup [vars] ``(apply hash-map (map vector (map keyword ~vars) (map eval ~vars))))` (with just one backtick) and ran into the issue here. I don't see a way to DRY out the let block :(

Comment: This works for me in the REPL. But if I wrap everything in a function and execute using `lein run`, it fails.