# clojure quoting inside let

Tags: clojure, macros, eval

Quoting (both syntax and non-syntax) seems to fail to detect vars inside a let statement:

```
(let [foo 1] (eval `(print foo)))
```

This will generate an error or use whatever prior value bound was bound to foo in (def foo bar). Is there a way to make the syntax quote use the "local" variables that let defined instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin

You were close, this should do the work (basically, you should unquote the local var in the quoted statement)

```
(let [foo 1] (eval `(print ~foo)))
```

Also, while `eval` is certainly a valid language function, what is the overall goal? There may be better ways altogether.

Frank

Answer (score 2):

Unquote to substitute the value:

```
(let [foo 1] (eval `(print ~foo)))
```

...or explicitly bind your variables:

```
(declare :^dynamic foo)
(binding [foo 1] (eval '(print foo)))
```

See [Variable scope + eval in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221716/variable-scope-eval-in-clojure) for details.