# Clojure eval scope issues

Tags: clojure, macros, eval

I am trying to do the following:
1. I have multiple agents who are maps that contain expressions.
(see first three lines of code)

2. What I want is, on a given date inside a let scope, the above expression form the map should bind to the local date.
   (rest of the lines)
3. What am i doing wrong, how should I approach this problem? Thanks.

--- all code below

```
(def dates [20171002 20171003])
(def date 20171002)
(def data (zipmap dates (repeatedly (count dates) #(ref {:entry true :exit true} )) ))


(dosync (alter (data 20171003) assoc-in [:entry] false))

(println data)
(def agent-1 {:entry-condition '((data date) :entry)})

;(eval (:entry-condition agent-1))
;(data date)

(def date-given 20171003)

(let [date date-given
      enter? (eval (:entry-condition agent-1))]
  (if enter? (println "hi") (println "correct")))

;; i need correct, not hi.
```

Comment: Don't store expressions and `eval` them: store functions and pass them arguments.

Comment: Thanks amalloy and Phil Cooper. Both of your ideas were useful, I went with functions and passing arguments for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, +1 to @amalloy comment that this eval is not you friend here ([some say evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)).

The root cause of the problem here is that **eval looks in the current namespace and not the current lexical scope**.  That is further explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221716/variable-scope-eval-in-clojure).

So, to rebind `date`, you need to use [binding](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) rather than [let](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) (at least for the date symbol).  It then also needs to be dynamic. In your def of date, you can make it dynamic with:

```
(def ^:dynamic date 20171002)
;; or better yet:
(declare ^:dynamic date)
```

then when you use it,

```
(binding [date date-given]
  (let [enter? (eval (:entry-condition agent-1))]
    (if enter?
      (println "NO")
      (println "correct") )) )
```