# clojure symbol resolve failure in eval

Tags: clojure

I'm a beginner in clojure. 
Could you help with the last 2 expression?
I cannot figure out why "Unable to resolve symbol: result in this context".
Thanks a lot!
(I'm trying to solve a problem in which there are references within list.)

```
(let [result ['(get result 1) 2]]
  (println (get result 1))          ;this can work
  (println (eval '(get result 1)))  ;error
  (println (eval(first result))))   ;error`
```

I expect `(map eval result)` to yield `[2 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` evaluates the forms you send it in the namespace bound to `*ns*` but with a blank lexical scope. So surrounding let values are not carried over. Defined vars, dynamic bindings etc however will be there. This post explains it well [Variable scope + eval in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221716/variable-scope-eval-in-clojure)

As an aside, `eval` is pretty powerful and confusing liquor to be sipping on as a beginner. In 6-7 years of programming in clojure I have never needed it.

Comment: Hi tks for your help!  Is there a better way to deal with this : [(+ 1 2nd) 0 (- 1st 3) (* 3rd 1st)]  (nth means a nth element inside the vec)

Comment: I believe you are looking for general advice, which SO is not well suited for. My recommendation would be the #beginner channel on the clojurians slack for such advice

Comment: eval does not start with a blank namespace. it evals in the contect of the namespace where eval was invoked

Comment: You are correct, it starts with a blank lexical scope. Thank you

Comment: one way to explain it is, as if the expression had been typed into the file as a top level form.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Not quite that, either. It evals in the context of `*ns*`. In an interactive repl, this is the namespace you are defining, but in the context of a non-interactive program `*ns*` is usually, I think, `user`. You can see this by running a program like `(def x 1) (defn -main [] (println (eval '*ns*)) (println (eval 'x)))`