# How can I get the value of a variable from a string in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I was doing a small project in clojure and I wonder if there is something like this:

```
(let [myvar "hello"] (println (read-var "myvar")))
```

where the "read-var" function finds that there is a variable with the name passed as string and returns it's value.

I found this [load-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-string) function but it seems that doesn't work with let bindings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

*I would say that in case you're in need of this kind of behaviour, you're probably not doing it right. in fact i can't even imagine why would someone want to do this in practice*

**but there is a way**

clojure macros have special implicit parameter, called `&env`, allowing you to get local bindings. So you could use this feature for local vars resolution at runtime:

```
(defmacro get-env []
  (into {} (map (juxt str identity)) (keys &env)))
```

notice that this macro doesn't require to know your desired var name at compile time, it rather just lifts the bindings from macro scope to runtime scope:

```
(let [x 10]
  (let [y 20]
    (get-env)))
;;=> {"x" 10, "y" 20}

(let [a 10
      b 20
      c 30
      env (get-env)]
  [a b c env])
;;=> [10 20 30 {"a" 10, "b" 20, "c" 30}]
```

even this

```
(let [a 10
      b 20
      c 30
      env (get-env)]
  (get-env))
;;=> {"a" 10, "b" 20, "c" 30, "env" {"a" 10, "b" 20, "c" 30}}

(let [x 10] (println ((get-env) "x")))
;;=> 10
;;   nil
```

so the behaviour is dynamic, which could be shown with this fun example:

```
(defn guess-my-bindings [guesses]
  (let [a 10
        b 20
        c 30]
    (mapv #((get-env) % ::bad-luck!) guesses)))

user> (guess-my-bindings ["a" "zee" "c"])
;;=> [10 :user/bad-luck! 30]
```

but notice that this `get-env` effect is limited to the bindings effective at it's expand-time. e.g:

```
(let [x 10
      y 20
      f (fn [] (let [z 30]
                 (get-env)))]
  (f))
;;=> {"x" 10, "y" 20, "z" 30} ;; ok

(def f (let [x 10
             y 20]
         (fn [] (let [z 30]
                  (get-env)))))

(f)
;;=> {"x" 10, "y" 20, "z" 30} ;; ok
```

but

```
(let [qwe 999]
  (f))
;;=> {"x" 10, "y" 20, "z" 30} ;; oops: no qwe binding
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of some approach to accomplish this if `read-var` has to be a function. If `read-var` were a macro and its argument is a *string literal* it would be possible to implement `read-var` so that the code that you wrote works. Another approach would be to build a macro `read-var` that uses `eval`, but that would also not be possible because `eval` cannot access local bindings as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6221829/1008794).

The closest I could come up with that (i) implements `read-var` as a function and (ii) lets you pass runtime values as arguments to `read-var` is the following:

```
(def ^:dynamic context {})

(defmacro with-readable-vars [symbols & body]
  `(binding [context (merge context ~(zipmap (map str symbols) symbols))]
     ~@body))

(defn read-var [varname]
  (get context varname))
```

and you can now  use this code like

```
(let [myvar "hello"]
  (with-readable-vars [myvar]
    (println (read-var "myvar")))) ;; Prints hello
```

The difference compared to your code is that you have to declare the variables that should be readable using the `with-readable-vars` macro. Obviously, you can build another macro that combines `let` and `with-readable-vars` if you like:

```
(defmacro readable-let [bindings & body]
  `(let ~bindings
     (with-readable-vars ~(vec (take-nth 2 bindings))
       ~@body)))

(readable-let [myvar "hello"]
  (println (read-var "myvar")))
```

The above code assumes you are not using advanced features such as destructuring for your bindings.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty simple here:

```
  (let [myvar "hello"]
    (println myvar))
  ;=> hello
```

Please see [this sample project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), esp. the list of documentation.

---

If you really want to pass the name of the variable as a string, you will
need the `eval` function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
  ))

(dotest
  (let [mydata "hello"]
    (is= "hello" mydata) ; works
  ))

(def myVar "hello") ; creates a Clojure 'Var':  tst.demo.coore/myVar

(dotest
   ; will fail if don't use fully-qualified namespace in string
    (let [parsed (clojure.edn/read-string "(println :with-eval tst.demo.core/myVar)")]
      (eval parsed)
      ;=> `:with-eval hello`
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I'm looking for, in my case what I need is a function that converts the string "myvar" into the myvar value specified in the let binding.