# Is property with exact cardinality one functional?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, description-logic, manchester-syntax

In an OWL-DL ontology, consider a property *p* with domain *D* and range *R* where *D* has a restriction over *p* to have cardinality of exactly one:

> D **SubClassOf** *p* **exactly** 1 Thing
>
> - (D ⊑ =1 p.Thing)

Can we then infer that *p* is a functional property, since each *d* of type *D* will have exactly one value for *p*? If this is correct, can a reasoner infer this knowledge?

Comment: It would depend on the domain definition on P. If the domain of P is D, then i guess it would be functional. Otherwise the proposed inference wouldn't be correct. If the domain is D union Q, then there could be Q's that had multiple P associated to them.

Comment: @DanielGarijo As stated in the question, "consider a *property P with Domain D*".  So in this case, D is a domain of P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OWL, a property is function when each individual has at most one value for the property. That "at most" is important;  it is permitted for something to have no value for the property.  (That means that a functional property in OWL is actually more like a possibly partial function in mathematics.)  That said, if every individual has a exactly one value for a property, then it clearly has *at most* one value for the property, so the property would, as you suspect, be functional. We can walk though a specific case, though, to be sure that this is general, and because we need to make sure that the property *p* here actually has at most one value for *every* individual.

> **Proof:** Suppose the property *p* has domain *D*, and *D* is a subclass of =1 *p*.*Thing*, so that every *D* has exactly one *p*
>   value.  Is it the case that every individual *x* has at most one value
>   for *p*? There are two cases to consider:
>
> 1. *x* is a *D*.  Then by the subclass axiom with the restriction, *x* must have exactly one value for *p*, and one is less than or equal to
>      one.
> 2. *x* is not a *D*.  Then *x* has no values for *p*.  If it did, then it would be in the domain of *p*, which is *D*, and that is a
>      contradiction.  Then *x* has zero values for *p*, and zero is less
>      than or equal to one.
>
> Then any individual *x* at most one value for the property *p*, which
>   is the definition of *p* being functional.  Thus, *p* is functional.
>   **QED**

An OWL DL reasoner should be able to confirm this, and it shouldn't be hard to check.

Comment: Just to support @JoshuaTaylor 's answer, there is a relevant section in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-guide-20040210/#simpleCardinality) regarding the difference between cardinality and functional properties: "... We specified hasVintageYear to be a functional property, which is the same as saying that every Vintage has at most one VintageYear. This application of that property to Vintage using the cardinality restriction asserts something stronger, that every Vintage has exactly one VintageYear".

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967784/qcrs-vs-functional-property where an example shows that using exactly 1 rather than functional is harder for current reasoners. This is expected, as having exactly one filler is a more stringent condition than having at most one filler.