# Constraint-programming in PHP

Tags: php, business-rules, constraint-programming

Are there any constraint-programming libraries for PHP? Something that would be capable of handling a situation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318888/solving-who-owns-the-zebra-programmatically).

Comment: My favourite would be:

     $result=popen("prolog <prologscript");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint programming libraries tend to be written in C/C++ for speed reasons, you can very easily create problems that are very costly to solve. Your best bets are:

- Find a C/C++ library that has an existing PHP wrapper (a quick Google doesn't turn up anything)
- Create your own wrapper around any of the libraries [mentioned here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming)
- Use a "black box" external program such as [Minion](http://minion.sourceforge.net/) which you interact with via the command line and text files

Alternatively take the Python code from the above example and call it from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

First-order predicate logic library can be found here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1344-PHP-Manipulate-analyze-and-prove-logic-propositions.html