# Einstein's Riddle solution using F#

Tags: algorithm, f#, zebra-puzzle

I'm looking for [Einstein's Riddle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle) solution using F# and I've found only [Einstein meets F#](https://jacerhea.wordpress.com/tag/einstein/).

Is F# suitable for this problem and are there any other implementations?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Closed for: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here." ??? In question are links to problem definition and to one solution using F#. I'm looking for another probably better. What's the problem with this question?

Comment: Please see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  There is no indication of prior effort in solving the problem, and in fact no real question about it.  You are essentially just requesting that someone write the code for you - those sorts of requests are off-topic here.

Comment: I don't want anyone to write code for me. No prior effort of solving - I only want to see any real and useful solution using F# to make idea about language power. I don't care much about Einstein's Riddle.

Comment: *"I don't care much about Einstein's Riddle"* - which is why this was closed.  *"Show me your code"* is [also off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: I disagree with you. How to learn language without any piece of code to study?

Comment: @Pavel : SO is not here to teach you to code, that's the point you're missing. SO is here to give _specific_ answers to _specific_ questions.

Comment: My question is specific, on-topic, and perfectly valid with [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Try to read FAQ again and think. Google provided me only one link (hard to find) to F# algorith solving the problem. If this question or answer is useful for you (anyone), please try to reopen my question. Thank you.

Comment: @PavelHodek - Perhaps you should take this up on meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @PavelHodek If you're trying to learn F#, there are some terrific resources for it.  Reply to my comment and I'll be happy to share them. But as it stands right now, your question (unintentionally, I'm sure) sounds as if it's saying "I want someone to write this code for me and I haven't even tried it yet." People are telling you that you should try something yourself first and then when you run into something you don't understand ask about that.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Why did you put "Show me your code" in quotes? Has anyone actually written that here?

Comment: @ildjarn "SO is here to give specific answers to specific questions". This looks like a specific question with specific answers to me. Is F# suitable? To some extent because it makes it easy to write logic solvers but it does not provide one so languages like Prolog would be more suitable. Are there other implementations? I don't know of any but I would also be curious to see and/or write some.

Comment: Here is a solver written in OCaml using a logic programming library called Hansei http://okmij.org/ftp/kakuritu/zebra.ml

Comment: @JonHarrop: I'm looking for a solution and show me your code are pretty similar. While I disagree that not a real question is the correct closing reason, the question seems too focused, since any "solution" to the question is not generally useful, beyond a coding sample, which there are plenty available.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318888/solving-who-owns-the-zebra-programmatically

Comment: @Jon: if you can't come to an agreement in the comments here, take it up on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Do *not* drag this into other, unrelated questions. I've deleted the irrelevant bits of this conversation to encourage this...

Comment: @Shog9 You're just adding to the noise. Let's just focus on getting this valuable content off StackOverflow and onto another forum where it can help people. Adam suggests FPish...