# Puzzle / Riddle to put unique combination of 1 to 8 numbers in 7 by 7 matrix

Tags: math, logic, puzzle

I'm badly stuck in below puzzle. Need your help in solving this:
8 guys booked 7 rooms in a hotel and decided to use only 4 rooms out of those 7, by making unique combinations of 2 people in such a way that neither a combination repeats in 7 days nor a person stays in a room twice.
E.g. if 1&2, 3&4, 5&6 and 7&8 stays in room1, room2, room3 and room4 then these combination will never stay together. They have to make different combination and change the room as well.
Another example, 1 can not stay again in room1 with anybody and same applies to others as well.

Can someone please solve this 7x7 matrix for me and help me out.. appreciate your efforts on this!

Comment: Create new question for another puzzle.  Do not erase this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
1&2       6&7       3&8       4&5  
5&6  1&3       4&8            2&7  
     5&7  1&4            2&8  3&6  
7&8       2&3  1&5       4&6       
     2&4  5&8  3&7  1&6            
3&4  6&8            2&5  1&7       
               2&6  4&7  3&5  1&8
```

[A program :)](https://eval.in/178022)

Comment: Thanks a lot Egor. Great stuff :)

Comment: Install Lua, put the program in file `program.lua` and run `lua program.lua`

Comment: Try to add corresponding tags to your question.  Maybe someone would help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

```
18          36 27 45
35 17    46 28      
47 25 16          38
26    37 15    48   
      58 23 14    67
   68 24    57 13   
   34    78    56 12
```

Actually, that's two solutions, since you could read
the rows as days and columns as rooms, or vice versa.
Each permutation of the numbers assigned to people, and each permutation of the rooms (columns), and each permutation of the days (rows) leads to another solution as well.

---

Here is Python code, based on [Egor Skriptunoff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236326/190597). The main idea is the same: Generate a list of all the pairs of people, and start placing them one at a time on the board. If there is no valid placement, then backtrack and try something else. In the code below a list of `tasks` records board states, so when a dead end is reached, the next candidate board state is popped off the `tasks` list. The trick is to enumerate all the possibilites in an organized, efficient way.

There are some minor differences:

- This code is iterative rather than recursive.
- The `solve` function tries to generate all solutions  instead of stopping after finding one.
- For simplicity, the initialization condition has been removed.

---

```
import itertools as IT
import collections
import copy
import random

people = range(1, 9)
days = range(7)
rooms = range(7)
pairs = list(IT.combinations(people, 2))


def solve():
    board = [[None for room in rooms] for day in days]
    pairidx = 0
    tasks = [(pairidx, board)]
    while tasks:
        pairidx, board = tasks.pop()
        if pairidx == len(pairs):
            yield board
            continue
        for day, room in IT.product(days, rooms):
            if not (used_day(board, pairidx, day)
                    or used_room(board, pairidx, room)
                    or used_day_room(board, day, room)):
                tasks.append(
                    (pairidx + 1, move(board, pairidx, day, room)))


def used_day(board, pairidx, day):
    """
    Return True if any person in persons has already been assigned a room
    """
    return any([person in pairs[idx] for idx in board[day] if idx is not None
                for person in pairs[pairidx]])


def used_room(board, pairidx, room):
    """
    Return True if any person in persons already been in the room
    """
    return any([person in pairs[row[room]] for row in board if row[room] is not None
                for person in pairs[pairidx]])


def used_day_room(board, day, room):
    """
    Return True if the room has already been assigned a pair for the day
    """
    return board[day][room] is not None


def move(board, pairidx, day, room):
    """
    Assign a pair to a room on a given day. Return the new (copy) of the board.
    """
    board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    board[day][room] = pairidx
    return board


def report(board):
    print('\n'.join(
        [' '.join([''.join(map(str, pairs[col])) if col is not None else
                   '  ' for col in row])
         for row in board]))
    print('-' * 20)

for solution in solve():
    report(solution)
```

---

By the way, this problem is very similar to the [Zebra problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318888/190597) and other constraint puzzles. You might look there for more ideas on how to solve your problem.

Comment: On the second day not all persons are paired (only 4 rooms must be occupied every day).